# Scroller for message content and then fixed text field at the bottom

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm just wondering how will I be able to achieve a chatbox with a fixed header & reply textbox. So far this is what I have.

```
.headerchat{
background-color: #336699;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
display: block;
}
.buddies {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    bottom: 30px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 205px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 235px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.messages {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    bottom: 30px ;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    left: 205px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 235px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    z-index: 100;   
}
.gray{
    color:#aaa;
}
.chat{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width: 235px;
}
.username{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #336699;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.username:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6699aa;
}
.conversation{
    width:235px;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
    float: left;
}
/*.conversationpicture{
    float:left;
}*/
.closecontainer{
    float: right;
}
.close, .close:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #fff;
}
.buddycontainer
{
    float:left;
}
.formchattext
{
    display: block;
    font-size:12px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:234px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ENydt/

What I want to achieve is to have a fixed header, scrollable content and fixed reply textfield.

I tried overflow-x: scroll; to both .buddies & .messages still no luck I am kind still newbie with this so I am really sorry. If you could just have a quick look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified Your code, this is

SAMPLE CODE:

```
.antiscroll-inner {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

DEMO:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ENydt/13/
```

**In future coding try to avoid write inline style for html elements**